# BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

here is my error:

I am getting this error , can any one help me on this.

```
> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.setEnvironment(Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:87)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Nov 21, 2013 12:54:38 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
> listenerStart Nov 21, 2013 12:54:38 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
> [/FLPalette] startup failed due to previous errors Nov 21, 2013
> 12:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
> Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext Nov 21, 2013 12:54:38 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop SEVERE:
> Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of
> class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or
> already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the
> ApplicationContext    at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:556)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4763)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5472)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431) Nov 21,
> 2013 12:54:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO:
> Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Nov 21, 2013 12:54:38 PM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
> ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Nov 21, 2013 12:54:38 PM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
```

pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.paypal.palette</groupId>
  <artifactId>FLPalette</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>FLPalette</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5</version>
</dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>  

  <dependency>
    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version> 
    </dependency>   
     <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>           
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>   
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>           
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

Answer (score 28):

This exception come due to you are providing listener `ContextLoaderListener`

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but you are not providing **`context-param`**
for your spring configuration file. like ***`applicationContext.xml`***
You must provide below snippet for your configuration

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If You are providing the java based spring configuration , means you are not using xml file for spring configuration at that time you must provide below code:

```
<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
    org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also
be specified for component-scanning -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.nirav.modi.config.SpringAppConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue here is that the version of `spring-web` that you're using (3.1.1-RELEASE) is not compatible with the version of `spring-beans` that you're using (3.0.2-RELEASE). At the top of the stack you can see the `NoSuchMethodError` which in turn triggers the `BeanFactory not initialized...` exception.

The `NoSuchMethodError` is caused because the method invocation `XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions()` in `spring-web` is trying to call `XmlBeanDefinitionReader.setEnvironment()` in `spring-beans` which doesn't exist in 3.0.2-RELEASE. It does however exist in 3.1.1-RELEASE - as `setEnvironment` is inherited from the parent `AbstractBeanDefinitionReader`.

To resolve, you'd probably be best to upgrade the `spring-beans` jar to 3.1.1-RELEASE. The version for this jar appears to be parameterized in your pom.xml and is controlled by the property `org.springframework.version` further down in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue until I removed the project in question from the server's deployments (in JBoss Dev Studio, right-click the server and "Remove" the project in the Servers view), then did the following:

1. Restarted the JBoss EAP 6.1 server without any projects deployed.
2. Once the server had started, I then added the project in question to the server.

After this, just restart the server (in debug or run mode) by selecting the server, NOT the project itself.

This seemed to flush any previous settings/states/memory/whatever that was causing the issue, and I no longer got the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error "BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before" was a consequence of a previous error that I didn't noticed in the server startup.
I think that it is not always the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the spring framework inside the springframework initialization Repository or controller annotation, the same class name can only exist a default instance, you can set the value name

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue twice once in upgrading to 3.2.18 from 3.2.1 and 4.3.5 from 3.2.8. In both cases, this error is because of different version of spring modules

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was due to the Network connection error that i was noticed in log.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused also by jvm version used to compile the project and the jvm supported by the servlet container.  Try to Fix the project  build path.  For example if you deploy on tomcat 9, use jvm 1.8.0 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

please mention "applicationContext.xml" in bean factory / ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was valid and it was due to using try with resource

```
 try (ConfigurableApplicationContext cxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "classpath:application-main-config.xml")) {..
}
```

It auto closes the stream which should not happen if I want to reuse this context in other beans.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error and I had not made any changes to the application config or the web.xml. Multiple tries to revert back some minor changes to code was not clearing the exceptions. 
Finally it worked after restarting STS.