# java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm working on spring and hibernate web app but I got error when several times run query on web app menu,

[stackoverflow](http://%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22UTF-8%22?%3E%20%3Cbeans:beans%20xmlns=%22http://www.springframework.org/schema/security%22%20%09xmlns:beans=%22http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans%22%20xmlns:xsi=%22http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance%22%20%09xsi:schemaLocation=%22http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans%20%09http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd%20%09http://www.springframework.org/schema/security%20%09http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd%22%3E%20%20%09%3Chttp%20auto-config=%22true%22%3E%20%09%09%3Cintercept-url%20pattern=%22/prs/**%22%20access=%22ROLE_USER%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3Cintercept-url%20pattern=%22/afterloginmember.html%22%20access=%22ROLE_USER%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3Cintercept-url%20pattern=%22/admin/**%22%20access=%22ROLE_ADMIN%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3Cintercept-url%20pattern=%22/afterlogin.html%22%20access=%22ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3Cform-login%20login-page=%22/login.html%22%20default-target-url=%22/afterlogin.html%22%20authentication-failure-url=%22/loginfailed.html%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3Clogout%20logout-success-url=%22/logout.html%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%3Caccess-denied-handler%20error-page=%22/accessdenied.html%22/%3E%20%20%20%09%3C/http%3E%20%09%20%09%3Cauthentication-manager%3E%20%09%09%3Cauthentication-provider%3E%20%09%09%09%3Cpassword-encoder%20hash=%22md5%22%20/%3E%20%09%09%09%3Cjdbc-user-service%20data-source-ref=%22dataSource%22%20%09%09%09%09users-by-username-query=%22%20%09%09%09%09%09select%20username,%20password,%20enabled%20%20%09%09%09%09%09from%20user%20where%20username=?%22%20%09%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%09authorities-by-username-query=%22%20%09%09%09%09%09select%20u.username,%20u.authority%20from%20user%20u%20%20%09%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%09%09where%20u.username=?%22%20%20%20%09%09%09/%3E%20%09%09%3C/authentication-provider%3E%20%09%3C/authentication-manager%3E%20%20%3C/beans:beans%3E) some posting said that the problem is the configuration but i have no idea

Error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PPBNI</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, 
        /WEB-INF/spring.xml, 
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml            
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- 404 Error Handler -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404-handler.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- SiteMesh -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and this is my spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/prs/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/afterloginmember.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/afterlogin.html" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/afterlogin.html" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessdenied.html"/>  
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
                select username, password, enabled 
                from user where username=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="
                select u.username, u.authority from user u 
                where u.username=?"  
        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

any help will be pleasure :D ~

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when we forget to write package/XML in ioc container
e.g.

```
Applicationcontext app=new classpathxmlapplicationcontext ("ourpackage/.xml");
```

so in above ioc container if we write XML file error will be removed

Answer (score 0):

This exception come due to you are providing listener ContextLoaderListener , but you are not providing context-param for your spring configuration file. like applicationContext.xml. goto below link for more detail information.answer is already available. [BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114955/beanfactory-not-initialized-or-already-closed-call-refresh-before)